# cloning and blue white screening in pet21a

Tags: molecular-biology

I am using pet21a as a carrier vector for my gene, with R.E BamHI and XhoI,in reverse primer I haven't added any extra nucleotide sequence so that it should code for the histag towards C-terminal. Am I doing so correctly?

Another question: after transformation to DH5alpha, I am getting only white colony(X gal stock was 20mg/ml about 200ul and IPTG 100mM stock about 40ulon surface of plate)... why I am not getting blue colonies?

Answer (score 2):

[pET21A](http://www.emdmillipore.com/CA/en/product/pET-21a+-DNA-Novagen,EMD_BIO-69740#overview) doesn't encode the lacZ α-peptide necessary for [blue-white screening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93white_screen) by complementation. Since [DH5α](https://www.thermofisher.com/ca/en/home/life-science/cloning/competent-cells-for-transformation/chemically-competent/dh5alpha-genotypes.html) has the lacZΔM15 background, only the lacZ ω-peptide is produced and thus β-galactosidase is inactive.